# ¿Cuál es la diferencia de estos "for"?

Tags: javascript

Hasta hoy he estado usando este tipo de `for` en js.

`for(i=0;i<100;i++)`

Pero hoy he empezado a tener fallos en un programa que estoy probando y no se porque se ha arreglado con este tipo de for:

`for(var i=0;i<100;i++)`

Que diferencia hay entre uno u otro? Cual se recomienda usar?

Comment: debes declaran previamente la variable i, para poder usar el primer método

Comment: @Maguz podrías brindar una respuesta con esa información (y agregando más detalles, claro está)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No hay ninguna diferencia. Son exactamente iguales, sólo que en el primero no estas declarando `i` explícitamente sino de manera implícita.

Ahora bien, con la nueva versión de JavaScript, ambas son malas a menos que **`i`** no sea relevante para alguna validación, ya que JavaScript buscará entre las diferentes capas hasta encontrar una variable **`i`** que sea global. En el mejor de los casos no encontrará nada pero si encuentra una variable **`i`** previamente declarada, terminará por sobreescribirla.

```
var i; // i declarada en alguna 
for (i=0;i>10;i++) {
  // hacer algo
}
console.log(i);  //ahora vale 10
```

Gracias al nuevo estandar ES6 (Varios navegadores ya lo implementan parcialmente) viene a nuestra ayuda **`let`**, que permite que las variables declaradas sólo afecten en el ámbito local, no como en el caso de **`var`**.

```
var i = -1; // i declarada en alguna 
for (let i=0;i<10;i++) {
  // hacer algo 
  console.log(i); // 1,2,3,..,9
}
console.log(i);  //sigue siendo -1
```

O sea, la mejor forma de usar, sería usando `let` si no vas a usar la variable en otro ámbito.

Puedes consultar más acerca de [let (MDN)](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Sentencias/let).

Comment: El caso que comentas aplica al primer caso, ya que se está declarando `i` como global. En el segundo caso, se convierte en global siempre y cuando no esté dentro de una función, en cuyo caso se aplicaría *hoisting*.

Answer (score 3):

Var indica la manera de declarar la variable, esto quiere decir que la variable será local, de lo contrario la variable será global si no mencionas cual tipo de error te ocasiona ni pones el resto del código será difícil saber porque te causa problemas.

En todo caso se recomienda siempre el uso de variables locales (con un var anteriormente), solo globales si es estrictamente necesario (por ejemplo guardar un valor para otra función o que necesites que se quedé como esta).

En cuanto al uso del for es exactamente lo mismo, solo que uno con variable local, y otro con variable global.

Cabe destacar que el var, solo se usa en el primer uso de la variable, es decir

```
function variable() {
  var x = 0;
  var y = x + 2
}
```

Como puedes ver en la segunda ocasión que usé var ya no se usó la palabra var ya que la variable ya fue declarada como local

Answer (score 1):

Entre estas dos formas no hay diferencia como mencionan en los comentarios anteriores, ahora bien, entre la utilización de la palabra LET y VAR si, ya que VAR solo crea una instancia de "i" y va añadiendo la cantidad a la variable, mientras que LET crea una nueva variable para cada iteración con el valor correspondiente.

```js
for ( var i = 1; i < 5; i ++ ) {
  setTimeout(function(){
    console.log("Usando VAR i: ", i );
  }, i * 1000)
}


for ( let i = 1; i < 5; i ++ ) {
  setTimeout(function(){
    console.log("Usando LET i: ", i );
  }, i * 1000)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No hay diferencia entre los for en sí mismos, la diferencia es la generación de la variable.

Cuando creas una variable sin la palabra reservada **var**, javascript entiende que la misma está declarada de manera global, lo que significa que la podrás utilizar en cualquier parte del código en tu archivo js, en cualquier función.

En cambio, si se utiliza **var**, la variable será local y solamente para uso en el alcance de la función en la que la declaraste.